# learning how to get functions to run

Tags: google-apps-script

Have found this code very similar to what I want to do.
The original posters intent was to be able to search a sheet for the word Hello and have it return the data for every line with the found text.

```
function testfindRow(){ ;// this function only to test the other one by giving it a parameter and using its result.
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var otherSheet=ss.getSheets()[1];// assuming there is a second sheet to copy to
    var datatocopy=findRow('Hello');
    if (datatocopy.length>0){
        otherSheet.getRange(otherSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,datatocopy.length,datatocopy[0].length).setValues(datatocopy);
    }
}
//
function findRow(item) { ;// the actual search function
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet=ss.getSheets()[0];
    var resultArray=new Array();
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(cc =0; cc < values.length; ++cc) {
        if(values[cc].toString().match(item)==item){// here you can eventually use string modifiers like toLowerCase() to allow for wider search criteria
            // or like this to search only in column D // if(values[cc][3].toString().match(item)==item){
                resultArray.push(values[cc]);
            };
        }
        Logger.log(resultArray);// the array of Rows in which the item was found,
        return resultArray ;// the returned value is a 2 dimensions array to use with setValues()

    }

}
```

I plan to modify to my use but first wonder, how does one get this piece of code to execute in the course of the script?  I can run testfindRow manually and it works nicely. Just not automatically.
My script runs all the way up to this point and then stops.
What's the key to running this code next?

With the answer from Cooper then I have now this code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('PROCESS')
      .addItem('Next Order', 'findAString')
      .addToUi();
}

function findAString(){
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh1=ss.getActiveSheet();
   var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
   if(!sh2){
     ss.insertSheet('Responses');
   }
   var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter a String");
   var rA=findRow(resp.getResponseText());
   if (rA){
     sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,rA.length,rA[0].length).setValues(rA);
   }
 }
```

I get a  PROCESS  menu option, subchoice  Next Order  and the input box pops up.
Can enter a string there and choose  OK  but then the script complains.

> ReferenceError: "findRow" is not defined.

A push forward?

Comment: You would probably run it inside of wrapper function.  The wrapper function might give users a prompt box to enter some text to search function and then you could take that text and run your function with your users input text as the parameter.

Comment: I don't think your code will work.  item is a string but match(item) returns an array so it will never be true match(item) == item.  Instead I would do  indexOf(item) >= 0.  When you say automatic do you mean by means other than script editor?  You could have a menu option or link to a button or on a timer.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the answer. I'm very new and didn't quite understand how to do this.

Comment: @TheWizEd  That's exactly it.  I have a button to push and get an input box so the data on that row can be captured.  I guess I need to create a new question to show the new code I've got to work with now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I tried to create a complete solution this time so you could see a little success. I have a function to create a menu and another to create a Results tab. Load all of the functions into the script editor and then run createMenu().  After that you can go back to spreadsheet view.  If you don't have a tab named Results then run the "Create a Results Tab" menu item and you'll get a new Results pages.  After that just keep running The "Find A String on Active Page" on the new menu.  Results for each search will be displayed in a dialog and all results will be appended to Results Tab.  The goal was to display rows that had atleast one cell that contained the search string even as a substring.

```
function createMenu(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem('Create a Results Tab', 'createResultsPage')
  .addItem('Find A String on Active Page', 'findAString')
  .addToUi();
}

function findAString(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Results');
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter a String");
  var s=resp.getResponseText();
  if(s){
    var rA=findRow(resp.getResponseText());
    Logger.log(rA);
    if (rA.length>0){
      sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,rA.length,rA[0].length).setValues(rA);
      var rows='<br /><h3>All Search Results are Appended to the Results Tab</h3><br />';
      rows+=Utilities.formatString('<br />These are the rows that contain: %s<br />',resp.getResponseText());
      for(var i=0;i<rA.length;i++){
        rows+=Utilities.formatString('<br /> %s',rA[i].join(' '));
      }
      rows+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
      if(rows){
        var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(rows);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Search Results')
      }
    }
  }else{
    throw('Error: Invalid Response');
  }
 }

function findRow(s) { ;// the actual search function
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var rA=[];
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
        if(vA[i][j].toString().indexOf(s)>-1){
          rA.push(vA[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.log(rA);
    return rA;
}

function createResultsPage(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(ss.getSheets().indexOf('Results')==-1){
    ss.insertSheet('Results')
  }
}

Please take a look at the help menu in the Script Editor and familiarize yourself with all of those references.  They are always changing so just about the time you think you know it all.  You can be pretty sure that you don't because something has been changed since the last time your visited them.
```

Comment: I'm getting an error trying to run this bit of code.
Reference Error findRow is not defined
I'm too green at this to see what the problem is.

Comment: VERY helpful. In the first column of data in the mainsheet is a time stamp supplied by Google forms.  I want the user to be able to copy a time stamp from the sheet and paste it into the prompt for processing.
What's happening is that I cannot capture the entire timestamp I'm guessing because of the space (i.e.  12/13/2018 20:44:36)  
Can the dialog box accept this kind of input?  The script works nicely if I just manually type  20:44:36  for example, but that's a much more cumbersome interaction than copy / paste.

Comment: It will take any string.  There may be a length limit but I'd imagine it to be quite long.  If you did your own dialog with an html file you could go get the timestamp for the user

Comment: Would it make a difference to know that the first field (Timestamp) in the sheet is generated by a google form?  I still am not able to capture and paste the timestamp into the dialog box. The script just doesn't run unless I capture only the time portion or only the date portion (not desirable).  Any special consideration to that column in the sheet being defined/created by the google form?

Comment: Seems there must be something to this... it seems like the timestamp is a "calendar" entry on the sheet? When I try to select the text, it pops out a calendar. But then I found that if I reformat the Timestamp column to text, then I can capture and copy as needed.  But that's an unwanted enduser interaction. Can I somehow tell the spreadsheet to reformat those cells to text once it populates, or upon refresh/opening the sheet perhaps?

Comment: If you have additional questions please ask them in another question.

Comment: Well I answered this for myself. Lightbulb finally came on and called itself MACRO... triggered on open the row is selected and set to text format. Works like a charm.

Comment: I found that by following the advice in SO's how to ask questions and mimimal complete verifiable example that one of two things will happen.  You'll either figure out the question on your own or you will have such as good question that someone here will answer the question very quickly.  So now when I start to run into problems I immediately start thinking about how  to prepare a good SO question and often that leads me to the answer on my own.